# How to get character count in 'Multiple Text 'column using Calculated Column?

Tags: wss-3.0

How can I get character count in 'Multiple Text 'column of Sharepoint?

Appreciate all the help!

-saumil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your column value you can just use .ToString().Length to get the number of characters.

Comment: Hi James, I got this link from net -- http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2010/04/02/add-character-or-word-count-to-sharepoint-multi-line-plain-text-field-and-restrict-input-length/   .... will this work on WSS 3.0 ?

Comment: Yep should do, I don't see any MOSS2007-only artefacts in that article, you only just really need the Content Editor Web Part to store the jQuery. Do note that my suggestion was under the impression that you were developing code in C#.

Comment: Thanks James. I am not a coder...so have to do with readymade solutions. I am not able to get positive results from above link. Here is what I did. I hosted jQuery file in a shared documents. Then I copy-pasted the code given in CEWP & tweaked the code so it points to location of my hosted jQuery file. I think it should work now, bit I am not able to see the Character Count in the said location. Am I missing out on something? Please help & oblige.

Comment: Did you tweak Line 05 of the code in the article to point to your list?

Comment: Sorry, I meant tweaked Line 05 in the code in the article to point to the Internal Name of your field, not your list.

Comment: No, I did not, what should I change it to ? Where could I find that name?

Comment: Source code has following data -- 
FieldName="SMS"
FieldInternalName="SMS"
FieldType="SPFieldNote"

Answer (score 1):

You can't with a calculated column, because this is not supported on a Multiple lines of text column. Other option is the answer above.